# How to test and document JRuby compatibility, for a gem with some C exts

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jruby, travis-ci

I have created a simple published gem, with source managed on github, and it runs builds on Travis CI when I commit.

Recently I added a dependency which happens to use a C extension. My builds on JRuby have failed with following message reported from Travis:

```
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
    /home/travis/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.3-d18/bin/jruby extconf.rb 
NotImplementedError: C extension support is not enabled. Pass -Xcext.enabled=true to JRuby or set JRUBY_OPTS or modify .jrubyrc to enable.
   (root) at /home/travis/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.3-d18/lib/ruby/shared/mkmf.rb:8
  require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1019
   (root) at extconf.rb:1
```

I have two related issues here:

1) I am at a loss on how I tell travis (presumably via the `.travis.yml` file?) to use the `-Xcext.enabled=true` flag. I am not sure if it is possible, but I suppose I could try out builds on my own machine in JRuby, and still ensure tests pass in JRuby, perhaps before a release.

*Update: It is not possible directly, and Travis policy because there may be issues in JRuby production environments according to http://about.travis-ci.org/docs/user/languages/ruby/*

*Second update: However, see accepted answer, it seems that Travis' policy can be over-ridden.*

2) I don't know whether supporting code which only works via enabling the C extension flag is considered standard enough that I could claim my library works in JRuby, even if I could get it to build on Travis. Am I in fact better off dropping support for JRuby until I can arrange to support it "properly". Or do I just declare "works in JRuby - provided you enable C extensions"?

In the case of the current dependency in my gem, I could find a work-around. However I am probably going to add some C extensions to the gem itself (for improved performance with some repeated maths), and won't have time in foreseeable future to add Java native support as well, mainly due to lack of knowledge/skill in Java. So I would like to understand what is considered best practice - or at least what is considered polite to JRuby users - when a gem has C native extensions but not Java equivalent.

When I Google for the error message in Travis, I don't find any suggested fixes. When I check in Stack Overflow, I am seeing a lot of questions from JRuby users trying to get specific native extension gems to work on their systems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you can pass it in with the JRUBY_OPTS environment variable, which you would do by adding this to your `.travis.yml` file:

```
env:
  global:
    - "JRUBY_OPTS=-Xcext.enabled=true"
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I can automate testing with JRuby again. I'm still not certain how far I should go in claiming JRuby compatibility,  but my best guess is "just the facts" - i.e. tests pass in JRuby with extensions enabled.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with the JRuby community, so I don't know at what point a library can properly claim to be "compatible", but at least it's possible to use it using JRuby in some cases.